# How to change my instance names on Prometheus

Tags: monitoring, prometheus

I'm monitoring multiple computers in the same cluster, for that I'm using prometheus.
Here is my config file **prometheus.yml**:

```yaml
# my global config
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s # Set the scrape interval to every 15 seconds. Default is every 1 minute.
  evaluation_interval: 15s # Evaluate rules every 15 seconds. The default is every 1 minute.
  # scrape_timeout is set to the global default (10s).

# Alertmanager configuration
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
    - static_configs:
        - targets:
          # - alertmanager:9093

# Load rules once and periodically evaluate them according to the global 'evaluation_interval'.
rule_files:
  # - "first_rules.yml"
  # - "second_rules.yml"

# A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
# Here it's Prometheus itself.
scrape_configs:
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
  - job_name: "Server-monitoring-Api"

    # metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
    # scheme defaults to 'http'.

    static_configs:
      - targets: ["localhost:9090"]
      - targets: ["localhost:9182"]
      - targets: ["192.168.1.71:9182"]
      - targets: ["192.168.1.84:9182"]
```

I'm new to Prometheus, I want to show the name of my target, i.e: rather than using for example `192.168.1.71:9182` I only want the target name to be shown, I have a research, I found this:

```yaml
relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__meta_ec2_tag_Name]
    target_label: instance
```

But I dont know how to use to relabel my targets(instances), any help will be appreciated, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

The snippet that you found should work only if you're using the EC2 service discover features of Prometheus (which doesn't seem your case since you're using some static targets).

I see a couple of options. You could expose directly in your metrics a different metrics (`hostname`) with the value of the hostname. Or you could use the [textfile collector](https://github.com/prometheus-community/node-exporter-textfile-collector-scripts) to expose the same metric as a static value (on a different port).

I recommend reading [this post](https://www.robustperception.io/how-to-have-labels-for-machine-roles) which explains why having a different metric for the "name" or "role" of the machine is usually a better approach than having a `hostname` label in your metrics.

It is also possible to add a custom label in the Prometheus config directly, something like (since you have your static targets anyhow). Finally, if you are already using the Prometheus node exporter you could use the `node_uname_info` metric (the `nodename` label).

```yaml
    - job_name: 'Kafka'
      metrics_path: /metrics
      static_configs:
        - targets: ['10.0.0.4:9309']
          labels:
            hostname: hostname-a
```

Comment: I did it but Prometheus dont want to start now :/

Comment: I think I messed up the indentation in the previous example. I copied one example from one of our Prometheus instances but you should still verify the indentations when you paste/modify it in your case. You can use `promtool check config <path>` to check the configuration before restarting prometheus.

Comment: Thanks for this information. The post is useful. It seems more intuitive to me to use a hostname type label, or perhaps even a serial number. Is there a most common best practice?